# Fix for chained select vue js component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, vue-component

I have 2 select dropdown boxes, one for home types and another for duration, i have been able to fetch data into the hometype dropdown but the duration dropdown is not fetching data.

Anyone, please help resolve

This is a vue component

```js
<script>
   export default {
       mounted() {
           console.log('Component mounted.')
       },
       data(){
           return {
              selectedHomeType: 0,
              HomeTypes: [],
              selectedDuration: 0,
              durations: []
           }
       },
       methods:{
           getHousetypes: function(){
             axios.get('api/getHousetypes')
             .then(function (response) {
                this.HomeTypes = response.data;
             }.bind(this));
             },
           getDuration: function() {
               axios.get('api/getDuration',{
                params: {
                  house_type_id: this.selectedHomeType
                }
             }).then(function(response){
                   this.Durations = response.data;
               }.bind(this));
           }
       },
       created: function(){
           this.getHousetypes()
       }
   }
</script>
```

```html
    <template>
    <div>
    
     <div class=" col-xs-4 text-center">
        
                            
      <label>Select HomeType:</label><div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
      <select name="Housetype" class='form-control centre' v-model='selectedHomeType' @change='getHousetypes()'>
        <option value='0' >Select HomeType </option>
        <option v-for='HomeType in HomeTypes' :value='HomeType.id' v-bind:key="HomeType.id">
          {{ HomeType.House_Type }}
        </option>

        
      </select>
                            </div>
    </div>                        
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4 text-center">
  
    

      <div class="form-group">
      <label>Select Durations:</label>
      <select class='form-control' v-model='selectedDuration'>
        <option value='0' >Select Durations</option>
        <option v-for='duration in durations' :value='duration.id' v-bind:key="duration.id">
          {{ duration.duration }}
        </option>
      </select>
      </div>




      </div>
      </div>
  </template>
```

```js
Sample JSON Data

Data for Hometypes

{
    "success": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "created_at": "2019-09-26 08:44:00",
            "updated_at": "2019-09-26 08:43:58",
            "House_Type": "1 Bedroom",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "created_at": "2019-09-26 08:44:00",
            "updated_at": "2019-09-26 08:43:58",
            "House_Type": "2 Bedroom",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "created_at": "2019-09-26 08:44:00",
            "updated_at": "2019-09-26 08:43:58",
            "House_Type": "3 Bedroom",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "created_at": "2019-09-26 08:44:00",
            "updated_at": "2019-09-26 08:43:58",
            "House_Type": "3 Bedroom Penthouse",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "created_at": "2019-09-26 08:44:00",
            "updated_at": "2019-09-26 08:43:58",
            "House_Type": "4 Bedroom",
            "status": "1"
        }
    ]
}

Data for Durations

[
    {
        "id": 13,
        "created_at": "2019-09-26 08:46:15",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-26 08:46:17",
        "house_type_id": 5,
        "duration": "9 Months",
        "status": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "created_at": "2019-09-26 08:46:15",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-26 08:46:17",
        "house_type_id": 5,
        "duration": "6 Months",
        "status": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "created_at": "2019-09-26 08:46:15",
        "updated_at": "2019-09-26 08:46:17",
        "house_type_id": 5,
        "duration": "3 Months",
        "status": "1"
    }
]
```

[See Image Representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfYXL.png)On Select HomeType 1 Bedroom Durations for 1 Bedroom show display eg 3 months, 6 months and 9 months in the Durations Select Box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mistakenly connected the wrong ajax method to the change event on the house type select box.
I think your logic is to update durations when you change the house type, but you are currently refreshing the house types available:

```html
      <select name="Housetype" class='form-control centre' v-model='selectedHomeType' @change='getDuration()'>
        <option value='0' >Select HomeType </option>
        <option v-for='HomeType in HomeTypes' :value='HomeType.id' v-bind:key="HomeType.id">
          {{ HomeType.House_Type }}
        </option>
      </select>
```

#### Update

Make sure your variable names are correct throught the code.
For example, you first define `durations` variable, but then try to assign `this.Durations` (notice the capital letter).

This might not be the issue, but may be confusing for other programmers.
I would suggest to use `snake_case` or `camelCase` to name your variables and stick to that convention you have chosen in your code. Usually, `PascalCase` is used for class names.

To quickly read more about different types of casing, check out this [medium post](https://medium.com/better-programming/string-case-styles-camel-pascal-snake-and-kebab-case-981407998841)

#### Update #2

To display data in Vue you can use `{{ your_variable_here }}` syntax anywhere in your component template.

That's really simple, just put the printing syntax where you need in the html template.

For example, to print the selection you can check if `selectedHomeType`'s value is different than 0 (because 0 would be "Select HomeType"'s index) with the `v-if` directive. Then inside this div put the code that you want to display when the given if condition is true.
In there you can use the `selectedHomeType` value to get the chosen element from the `homeTypes` array.

```html
<div v-if="selectedHomeType !== 0">
    <p>The selected HomeType is: {{ this.homeTypes[selectedHomeType - 1].House_Type }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Tested it now, it still did not fetch durations, only home types are still been loaded

Comment: I have updated my answer, try that and let me know!

Comment: Thanks @mdexp for the update, everything works perfectly you're awesome.

Comment: Lets say i want to bind the data of selected checkbox to text in a div, for example <div> I want a {{ 'Selected Hometype eg 1  bedroom' }} house </div> how do i achieve this thanks newbie to vue

Comment: I have updated once more my answer. I suggest you follow a course like [this one](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step) on Laracasts (this course is for free, I'm not sponsoring, just giving you an advice, you're free to choose whichever course you prefer)

Comment: I have tested and it works, will follow your advice on the course kind regards